# New Ubuntu user: What is the repository? How do I access it? How do I find and use WINE?

Tags: 12.04, wine, repository

I just started using Ubuntu yesterday because Windows has been nothing but headaches for nearly 20 years now. There are only a few Windows-based applications I want to continue using, and it seems something called WINE will probably enable me to go on using those applications. But ... all the directions I'm finding for how to get and use WINE are confusing the heck out of me.

http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu provides a link to download WINE, but before using it the page says you first must add the WineHQ PPA Repository. I don't even know what that is. Per the directions, I opened Ubuntu Software Center, but I don't see Edit ... which makes following the rest of the directions impossible.

Please help. And please use small words, lol, because I know nothing about computer programming. I only know Microsoft is evil and I'm sick of dealing with it...

Comment: Now I have an additional problem. I click on Ubuntu Software Center, and it fails to launch.

Comment: then ask it in a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have Wine in the default package list in Ubuntu. First you need to update the list of packages, so go to Software Updater. The first thing it does is refresh the package list. then it prompts for upgrade of actual packages. You may deny it. Then search for Wine in the software center.

There is also another way of installing Wine. Open Terminal from the Dash. type the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update #this updates the software list for you. it should be done after a fresh install
sudo apt-get install wine #it installs wine for you
```